# Understanding Rvalue Reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

Is this undefined behavior? If not, what is the behavior?

```
// In some external library with, say, header "a.h"
void f(int &&x) {
  x = 5;  // Which memory does this assignment apply to?
}

#include "a.h"
int main() {
  f(7);
  // At this point, where is the value of 5?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, and 5 is still 5.

Comment: But where did the assignment `x = 5` go to?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure *what* it does, but I'm quite sure it's well-defined.

Comment: Inside `f`, a *temporary* of is created with value `7`, exactly as if we wrote `f(const int& x)`, only this is not `const`. `x` refers to this temporary, and since it's not `const`, we can change it. However, this is only a local variable so outside `f()`, this value is lost.

Comment: I knew I just saw this somewhere. http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/Beginning/references.php

Comment: does your code compile?

Comment: @tristan [Yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/186835c11fda0bd5).

Comment: It compiles due to the fact that "7" is a const literal. If you pass a variable it will break.

Comment: @Dimitrios If you pass a variable, [f(int&&) simply won't match](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89461cbe39731183) - you would need `f(int)`, `f(int&)`, or `f(const int&)`.

Comment: @iavr I think we agree.

Comment: Why can't I compile this code? It shows 2 errors..`error: expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token` and
`error: 'x' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: And also the link chris mentioned says `set_int(0);` can't be done. Because `This is due to the fundamental nature of an lvalue. An lvalue is a thing that will be around for a while. But 0 is not a thing that will be around for a while. In fact, as soon as set_int(0) returns, the 0 will cease to exist. Thus, it makes no sense to allow 0 to bind to an lvalue reference. After all, when you set 0 to 5, what's the point?`

Comment: Ok I know the answer of the previous comment about not being able to done. I should have read carefully the link chris provided. But I don't understand why my code can't be compiled.

Comment: @Tahlil What compiler do you use? It is probably from the stone ages before C++ had rvalue references.

Comment: In the readme file on `mingw` folder in my windows 8 OS I see the GCC version is `=== TDM-GCC Compiler Suite for Windows ===
---        GCC 4.6 & 4.7 Series        ---
***   Standard MinGW 32-bit Edition    ***`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 8.5.3 describes initialization of references (including rvalue references).

It says:

> Otherwise, a temporary of type “cv1 T1” is created and initialized
>   from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference
>   copy-initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the
>   temporary.

So, a temporary of type int is bound to the rvalue reference, and thrown away immediately after the call returns.

Section 12.2 (Temporaries) gives examples very similar to yours.